# How to Fix Uncaught TypeError: players.setAttribute is not a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just Beginner and I got Error like Uncaught TypeError:  players.setAttribute  is not a function while submit action.How to fix the problem ? Please share your knowledge.

'''

```
//selecting all required element
const selectBox = document.querySelector(".select-box"),
selectXBnt = selectBox.querySelector(".playerx"),
selectOBnt = selectBox.querySelector(".playero"),
playBoard = document.querySelector(".playboard"),
allBox = document.querySelectorAll("Section span"),
players = document.querySelectorAll(".players");


window.onload = ()=>{//once window load
    for (let i = 0; i < allBox.length; i++) {// add onclick attribute in all avaiable section's span 
        allBox[i].setAttribute("onclick", "clickedBox(this)");
        
    }
    selectXBnt.onclick = ()=>{
        selectBox.classList.add("hide");//hide the box when click
        playBoard.classList.add("show");//show the Playboard after clicking 

    }
    selectOBnt.onclick = ()=>{
        selectBox.classList.add("hide");//hide the box when click
        playBoard.classList.add("show");//show the Playboard after clicking 
        players.setAttribute("class", "players active");
    }
    
}
let playerxIcon = "fas fa-times";// class name of fontawesome cross 
let playeroIcon = "far fa-circle";// class name of fontawesome circle
function clickedBox(element){

}
```

'''

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRTeV.png)

Comment: We need to see a bit more of the code, but seems like `players` is missing the `setAttribute` method you want to call on it. Can you show us how `players` comes to life?

Comment: The `document.querySelectorAll()` method returns a `NodeList` - ie an array-like structure of DOM `Elements`. Even though DOM `Elements` do have a `setAttribute()` method, you can not call it on the `NodeList` as a whole.

Comment: So, I think in `selectXBnt` you want to use `players[0].setAttribute()` and in the other one `players[1].setAttribute()` (you might have to switch the numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do the same what you did to `allBox`:

```
//selecting all required element
const selectBox = document.querySelector(".select-box"),
selectXBnt = selectBox.querySelector(".playerx"),
selectOBnt = selectBox.querySelector(".playero"),
playBoard = document.querySelector(".playboard"),
allBox = document.querySelectorAll("Section span"),
players = document.querySelectorAll(".players");


window.onload = ()=>{//once window load
    for (let i = 0; i < allBox.length; i++) {// add onclick attribute in all avaiable section's span 
        allBox[i].setAttribute("onclick", "clickedBox(this)");
        
    }
    selectXBnt.onclick = ()=>{
        selectBox.classList.add("hide");//hide the box when click
        playBoard.classList.add("show");//show the Playboard after clicking 

    }
    selectOBnt.onclick = ()=>{
        selectBox.classList.add("hide");//hide the box when click
        playBoard.classList.add("show");//show the Playboard after clicking
        for(let i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
        {
          players[i].classList.add("active");
        }
    }
    
}
let playerxIcon = "fas fa-times";// class name of fontawesome cross 
let playeroIcon = "far fa-circle";// class name of fontawesome circle
function clickedBox(element){

}
```

However I have a feeling this is not going to work as you expected, as I suspect there are multiple players and all of them going to get `active` instead of only specific player.

Comment: Seems like he is trying to change class of one particular button as per UI provided by him. He did small mistake while defying players he did `players = document.querySelectorAll(".players");
` instead of `players = document.querySelector(".players");`

As it should be clicked buttons class need to be changed.

Comment: You could be correct. With the amount of information we got it's 50/50 ;)

Comment: Yup :D lets wait for @Praveen to come back!

Answer (score 0):

current:

```
players = document.querySelectorAll(".players");
```

correct:

```
players = document.querySelector(".players");
```

querySelectorAll will give you access to all its child but you can't apply setAttribute to it directly. To apply on child you need to do select query on child.

For more reference you can follow this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)